# Can't detect fullscreen AVPlayerViewController transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

The old "MPMoviePlayerController" that's now deprecated had a delegate for "MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullScreen".

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1620898-mpmovieplayerwillenterfullscreen

Can't find anything similar for the current standard, "AVPlayerViewController" after looking through the docs.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontrollerdelegate

How do I implement a delegate for AVPlayerViewController when based on the toggling of fullscreen of the player?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any built in notification as you mentioned.  You could observe changes to the videoBounds of the AVPlayerViewController:

```
    [self.playerViewController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"videoBounds" options:0 context:NULL];
```

Then use your own logic once the observation comes in to determine whether it was toggled to full screen or another bounds change:

```
    - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == self.playerViewController && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"videoBounds"]) {
        // check your playerViewController videoBounds here compared to what they were previously
        // they could change outside of toggleFullScreen (rotation for example)
    }
}
```

As noted in my comments there, rotation will most likely cause a videoBounds change as well so you'll need to account for that in your logic.